# dim of quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $V=Mat_n(K), n \ge 1$ and  3 subspaces $U_1,U_2,U_3 \subset V$ respectively the scalar, diagonal and upper triangular matrices. Calculate dimension of $U_3/U_1 \ \ U_3/U_2  \ \ V/U_1  \ \ V/U_2  \ \ V/U_3$.

I know that  $\dim(V/U)=\dim(V)-\dim(U)$. Scalar matrix has the same dim as V. What about the rest?

Comment: Scalar matrices form a subspace of dimension 1. I don't know what you mean by "the same dim as V"...

Comment: Let $U_1$ scalar, so $A \in U_1$   $A=c I$. I is identity matrix. Identity matrix has dim=n. right?

Comment: The identity matrix is just one vector in $V$. Scalar matrices are scalar multiple of the identity. It is a line in $V$ with direction vector being the identity. Hence a 1-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension, in this case, is the number of *different* not identically zero elements from $K$ that show up in your three types of matrices. For "scalar" matrices, there is a *single* number repeated along the diagonal (and you don't count the surrounding $0$s), so $\dim U_1 =1$. For diagonal matrices, there are as many *different* not identically zero elements as entries on the diagonal, and this is $n=\dim U_2$. Finally, for triangular matrices there are $n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots +1$ *different* not identically zero elements, which gives $\dim U_3 = \frac {n(n+1)} 2$. Of course, $dim V=n^2$ and you do the rest.